# Programatically create form and display bitmap in the form?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, graphics, monodevelop, gdk

Platform: UBUNTU
IDE: MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3
Language: C#.NET

I have created a function which makes a screenshot and returns that screenshot as a Bitmap. Like this:

/* Variable to store bitmap data in */
Bitmap bmp;

/* Create screenshot. Return result to variable 'bmp' */
getScreenShot(bmp);

My question is:

How do I create a form/window (or whatever makes sense) which displays the screenshot (i.e. the bmp data) ? I want to do it programmatically.

I tried to do it like this:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Form form = new Form
        {
            Name = "Screenshot Displayer",
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 800),
                            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 170),
                             Visible=true
        };



        /* Get screenshot */
        Gdk.Global.InitCheck(ref args);
                    screenCapture.getScreenShot(bmp);

        form.BackgroundImage = bmp;
        form.Show();






    }
```

I tried this as well and it doesn't work.

```
PictureBox P = new PictureBox();  
Bitmap bmp = null;  
Form form = new Form  
{  
    Name = "Screenshot Displayer",  
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 800),  
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 170),  
    Visible=true  
};  

bmp = new Bitmap("screenshot0.bmp");  
P.Image = bmp;  
form.Controls.Add (P);  
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a PictureBox that docks fill in the form.Then display screenshot like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image=bmp;
```

Comment: Can you show me an example? I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work.

Comment: PictureBox P = new PictureBox();
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            Form form = new Form
            {
                Name = "Screenshot Displayer",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 800),
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 170),
                Visible = true
            };

            bmp = new Bitmap(@"example.bmp");
            P.Image = bmp;
            P.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Controls.Add(P);
            form.Show();

Comment: what if you do not want to have a picture boxes on the form and want to draw it on the background like on the form

Comment: 1.Generate bitmap.You can draw or get from file.eg:Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"example.bmp");
2.Set bmp as background of the form.eg:form.BackgroundImage=bmp;

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do I create a form/window (or whatever makes sense) which displays the screenshot (i.e. the bmp data) ? I want to do it programmatically."*

Try : 
(compiling the below should display your `Bitmap`, study the code and ask anything) :

```
//# Declare a PictureBox (as bitmap container)
PictureBox pbx;

//# Setup the PictureBox
pbx = new PictureBox
{
    Name = "pictureBox99",
    Size = new Size(640, 480),
    Location = new Point(0, 0),
    Visible=true
};

//# Link PictureBox to code for reference
this.Controls.Add(pbx);

// Add your Bitmap as source
pbx.Image = your_Bitmap_object;
```

Comment: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PictureBox' could not be found`

Comment: Are you using WinForms? You need to drag/drop a PictureBox component into your app.